# How can I stop a Bootstrap alert from automatically disappearing?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I want my button to display an alert after its clicked and stay there until its closed.

On my webpage the alert flashes on the screen for a split second every time the button is pressed.

On my jsfiddle the alert appears until its closed but does not reappear when the button is clicked again.

http://jsfiddle.net/g1rnnr8r/108/

Any ideas?

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>Completed!</strong> Form successfully submitted...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
<style>
    .alert {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

**js**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('button').click(function () {
            $('.alert').show()
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: 
[See DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g1rnnr8r/109/)

When you use `data-dismiss="alert"`, it totally remove the `alert` div. So, you try like this.

```
<body>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
        <strong>Completed!</strong> Form successfully submitted...
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.alert').show()
    }); 

    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('div').hide();
    }); 
});
```

CSS:

```
.alert{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Works well on jsfiddle, for some reason on my webform it makes the button refresh the page.

Comment: @rks , If the submit button is refreshing the page, you can use a `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Still wont working, when i use `event.preventDefault();` the page doesn't reload at all. Not sure why its working on jsfiddle and not my page, I think it may be an issue with something on my web form.

Comment: How did you use `event.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: `$('button').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
    }); `

Comment: Try like this: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(event){ 
         event.preventDefault();
        $('.alert').show()
    }); 
});`